# Как удалить субмодуль?

Tags: git, git-submodule

Имеется субмодуль в git репозитории. Добавлялся так:

```
git submodule add <git_module_url> libs/<module_name>
```

Теперь он перестал быть нужным, как его удалить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Встроенных средств для удаления субмодулей нету. Нужно сделать седующее:

- Удалить (отредактировав) упоминание о модуле из `.gitmodules`;
- Удалить из `.git/config`;
- Выполнить `git rm --cached <submodule_path>`;
- Закомитить и удалить файлы модуля.

Так же можно воспользоватся следующей командой

```
git config -f .git/config --remove-section submodule.<submodule_path>
git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule.<submodule_path>
```

Comment: к сожалению это и есть правильный способ. Может в ближайших версиях добавят команду для этого.