# Файлы в одной папке не индексируются и не отправляются на GitHub

Tags: git, github

Прошу подсказать.

Заливал проект Asp.Net MVC через Git Bash на GitHub. Но ключевая папка проекта почему-то копируется без файлов, т.е. пустая папка. Остальные файлы проекта, включая другую папку копируются нормально. Скрин прилагаю.[image: DataProject копируется без файлов]

Также прилагаю скрин, что папка DataProject не хочет индексироваться, точней файлы внутри неё - [image: Не проиндексировано]

В чем проблема? Я писал все как в инструкции:

```
git add .
git commit -a"name"
git push
```

Также пробовал заходить отдельно в папку DataProject и там прописывать `git add .; git commit` , выходил на уровень выше проверял статус и красное пропадало.....но файлы по-прежнему на ГитХаб не загружались. 
Поодскажите, пож-т.

Comment: Олег, я поздновато заметил ваш вопрос. Надеюсь, решение ещё пригодится. Если появятся вопросы — пишите комментарии к ответу, тогда я получу уведомление и смогу вам ответить.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## В чём причина такого поведения

Вот эта строка:

```
modified: DataProject (modified content)
```

Указывает на то, что папка DataProject — это ещё один репозиторий внутри основного репозитория. Это называется субмодуль (submodule). Гитхаб показывает субмодули специальной серой иконкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Субмодуль — это полностью самостоятельный репозиторий. У него свои данные, свои коммиты, своя история. Внешний, «родительский» репозиторий не может сохранять изменения файлов внутри субмодуля. Он знает (сохраняет в своих коммитах) только следующее:

- В каком пути лежит субмодуль (например, `корень проекта/DataProject`).
- На какой коммит субмодуля нужно смотреть.

Похоже, что у вас такая структура:

```
~/Downloads/DataProject                  # это ваш проект
   | 
   → ~/Downloads/DataProject/DataProject # а это субмодуль внутри него
   → ~/Downloads/DataProject/packages    # просто папка
```

Скорее всего субмодуль здесь не нужен, и вы его добавили по ошибке.

Обратите внимание: папка `packages` не должна сохраняться в репозитории — добавьте её в gitignore. (Спасибо [Pavel Mayorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603132/asp-net-mvc-5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-github/641764#comment911097_641764) за наблюдательность)

## Как починить репозиторий

### Правильный путь — удалить субмодуль

Инструкция здесь: [Как удалить субмодуль?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/130691/181472)

### Простой путь — начать заново

Если вы только начали работу над проектом, можно [удалить историю Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428154/181472) и создать новый репозиторий. Все ваши файлы останутся на месте. Если беспокоитесь — сделайте бэкап в новую папку или архив.

1. Удалите старый репозиторий:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/DataProject
   # Удаляем репозиторий
   rm -rf .git
   # И файл с конфигурацией субмодуля.
   rm -f DataProject/.git
   # И список субмодулей
   rm -f .gitmodules
   ```
2. Теперь заново инициализируем репозиторий. Убедитесь, что вы находитесь в той же папке!

   ```
   git init
   ```
3. Добавьте [файл `.gitignore` для VS](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) в корень проекта. Теперь лишние файлы не будут сохраняться в Git.
4. Сохраните `.gitignore` в коммит:

   ```
   git add .gitignore
   git commit -m'add gitignore'
   ```
5. Добавьте оставшиеся файлы.

   ```
   git add .
   git commit -m'message'
   ```
6. Теперь снова настройте удалённый репозиторий и перепишите его новой историей.

   ```
   git remote add <адрес удалённого репозитория на гитхабе>
   git push -uf origin master:
   ```

Comment: Добавлю: судя по всему, само наличие субмодуля в такой ситуации - ошибка. Как и отсутствие gitignore (папка packages на гитхаб попадать не должна!)

Comment: @PavelMayorov ага, про ошибку как раз дописываю. А про packages ценное наблюдение, спасибо! Надеюсь, автор вопроса когда-нибудь это всё прочитает.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Сомневаюсь, писать ли подробно о том, как пошагово починить проект, или предложить `rm -rf .git` и начать с начала?

Comment: ИМХО тут проще `rm -rf .git` (два раза!). Кстати, gitignore лучше взять стандартный для студии, там же не только packages лишняя будет...

Comment: @PavelMayorov удаление субмодулей вообще плохо поддерживается. Насколько я знаю, до сих пор нужно руками лезть в недра `.git`.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/2790048

Comment: @PavelMayorov а где вы берёте стандартный .gitignore для студии?

Comment: есть где-то на гитхабе репощиторий с гитигнорами на все случаи жизни. Но вообще-то студия сама обычно его создает.

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте принудительно добавить файлы в индексируемую область, например:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged DataProject
```

Еще посмотрите, что у вас в гитигноре, возможно, там и прописана эта папка.

Comment: Гитигнор я вообще не добавлял, потому файла этого нет. А вот после принудительной индексации измениласб ошибка -  git commit -m"CCDSD"
On branch master
Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   DataProject (modified content)

no changes added to commit