# не корректно выполняется push

Tags: git, github, git-push

После создания пустого репозитория, заливаю проект на github так:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Init commit"
git remote add origin <url моего репозитория>
git push -u origin master
```

На github получаю такую ситуацию:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В папку `app` войти не могу, значит ее содержимое в комит не попало?.Как это исправить?

**UPD:** Проверил `git status` получил:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   app (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: а в папке app что то есть? может это ссылка куда то или все содержимое добавлено в gitignore?

Comment: @KoVadim, в app по сути весь проект и лежит

Comment: а если сделать `git add app`, а потом `git status` покажет, что папка добавилась?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что в папке `app` уже есть папка `.git` и она сама по себе является репозиторием. Или же по какой-то другой причине `app` считается подмодулем, а не нормальной папкой.

Comment: @yeputons, вы абсолютно правы, там есть папка ".git" .Если ее удалить должно получится?

Comment: @yeputons, спасибо за наводку!все вышло

Comment: @yeputons это был именно субмодуль. На это указывает и иконка на гитхабе, и вывод `git status`. Для удаления субмодуля недостаточно удалить `.git` из папки субмодуля.

Comment: @UjinUkr у вас там был субмодуль, возможно вы его случайно добавили. Подробности тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/603132/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin, изначально проект подключался через Android Studio, видимо модуль был добавлен именно ней